# Why use VBO's and/or IBO's as opposed to just simple Vertex Data?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

So what's the **benefit** to using VBO's (Vertex Buffer Objects) and IBO's (Index Buffer Objects) as opposed to using simple Vertex Data?

When is a good time to **use** them? Would it be more **complicated** to load a **3D model** into them? If so, what's the benefit? And how are VBO/IBO's **different** from each other?

From my understanding you create Data as Vertices, Normals and so on, then you put them into regular **buffers**. When you make a VBO/IBO, you still need the buffer, so why would you need a separate buffer for VBO's and IBO's? Is it just a matter of performance, or are there other advantages?

I suppose this would all be **leveraged** against the difficulty of adding VBO/IBO code as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffer Objects are memory allocated by the OpenGL context directly, this means that how and where that memory is allocated is up to the implementer of the OpenGL driver.

This offer the advantage that the driver can allocate that memory in the GPU or perform  optimizations that are hidden to the OpenGL client but greatly increase performance (for example you avoid extra mem copys).

You should start using them as soon as possible, they may think complex but in fact is quite easier and once you climb that learning curve, you won't go back.

Happy coding!